# Loop Issues with objects in C++

Tags: c++, loops, object, while-loop, ofstream

I have to create a simple code that is supposed to create a .txt file as an output, containing a list fo notations with this format. (time ; topic ; comment)
the code has to run a loop using a struct function showed below:

```
struct annotation_t {
string topic;
string comment;
time_t stamp;
};
```

so the user can input the notations as many times he wants till he decides to go out. This is what I did so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;
struct annotation_t {
string topic;
string comment;
time_t stamp;
};

int main()
{

int q = 0;
std::vector<annotation_t> obj;

do
{  

annotation_t temp = {};

cout<< "input your topic: ";
cin >> temp.topic ;
cout<< "input yourfeedback: ";
cin >> temp.comment ;
cout<< "input your time stamp: ";
cin >> temp.stamp ;
cout<< "exit?";
cin >> q;

obj.push_back(temp);


} while (q != 0);  


ofstream myfile("annotation.txt");
char time[1000];

for(int i = 0;i<50;i++) 
{
struct annotation_t obj[i];  
myfile<<obj[i].stamp <<" "; // write in file
myfile<<obj[i].topic <<" ";// write in file
myfile<<obj[i].comment; // write in file   
myfile<<"\n";

}
cout<<"\nFile Created with Data with name annotation.txt \n";

myfile.close();


system("Pause");

}
```

I have a problem when it come to exit. if I input any value( even 0) I get a segmentation fault so i am not able to quit the loop and save my file in the txt, or re run it if I want to input more.. Let me know your thoughts.thanks

Comment: Look at @Tas answer. You may want to change the variable name from i to j in second loop just to avoid confusion.

Comment: please don't deface your question

Comment: Paulit it was a bug i was trying to flag to positive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem with declaration 'obj' object.
This is wrong :

```
struct annotation_t obj[i];
```

Try this instead :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;
struct annotation_t {
string topic;
string comment;
time_t stamp;
};

int main()
{

int q = 0;
struct annotation_t obj[1000]; //msf

int i=0; //msf
do
{

cout<< "input your topic";
cin >> obj[i].topic ;
cout<< "input yourfeedback";
cin >> obj[i].comment ;
cout<< "input your time stamp";
cin >> obj[i].stamp ;
cout<< "exit?";
cin >> q ;
i++; //msf

} while (q != 0);  


ofstream myfile("annotation.txt");
int count=i; //msf

for(i = 0;i<count;i++)  //msf
{
myfile<<obj[i].stamp <<" "; // write in file
myfile<<obj[i].topic <<" ";// write in file
myfile<<obj[i].comment; // write in file   
myfile<<"\n";

}
cout<<"\nFile Created with Data with name annotation.txt \n";

myfile.close();


system("Pause");

}
```

I changed your code in many positions that I commented with '//msf'.
I don't have C++ compiler in hand then I hope it will be compiled without errors.

Comment: I have a segmentation fault error when I get to "exit?"

Comment: Excuse me I am late. Please delete the line 'system("Pause");'

Comment: The code looks very good, one more thing, what I have to do to make sure the user will be able to input words using spaces? Because for example if I write more than one word on obj.topic string I'm not able to input at obj.comment, it goes straight to obj.stamp. The issues is that I have to keep "string" and not change to "char[]"

Comment: Use this: 'std::getline(cin, obj[i].topic);' instead of: 'cin >> obj[i].topic ;'

Comment: But in this case on the next iterations it will go straight to obj.comment, skypping obj.topic after the "exit"

Comment: @user6368995 Excuse me I didn't understand again. What means 'after the "exit".'

Comment: At the 2nd iterations of the loop for example, it skips the obj.topic part and goes straight to the obj.comment

Comment: @user6368995 OK. Add 'std::getchar();' after 'cin >> q ;'. It may solve the problem. I don't access a computer now to test it.

Answer (score 3):

```
int i=0;
struct annotation_t obj[i];
```

You're making an array of `annotation_t` objects of `0` size

```
cin >> obj[i].topic ;
```

Then attempting to access the first element.

Consider using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead, which will allow you to dynamically change the size of your container to allow the user to input as many as they'd like:

```
// Empty container
std::vector<annotation_t> obj;
do
{
    // Create temporary
    annotation_t temp = {};
    // Accept input:
    cin >> temp.topic;
    ...
    // Add to container:
    obj.push_back(temp);
}
```

In your beneath `for` loop, you are doing the same thing as above

```
for(int i = 0;i<50;i++) 
{
struct annotation_t obj[i];
```

Plus, you are creating a new container. You probably intend to use the container from above, which will change your loop into:

```
// Store the contents of the now populated obj from above
for (auto& a : obj)
{
    myfile << a.stamp << " ";
    myfile << a.topic << " ";
    myfile << a.comment << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank for the answer @Tas but what could be the best way if want to maintain "struct" ?

Comment: You keep the `struct`. Nothing here changes `annotation_t`, just the way you _store_ `annotation_t` objects (using a `std::vector` instead of an array)

Comment: I have a segmentation fault when I get to "exit?", I am not able to exit all re run the loop if I want to input more.

Comment: Did you update both instances of your loop? Beneath the `do while` you have another `for` loop which creates an empty array as well. It's likely you want to continue using your vector from above

Comment: I did not update the for loop after my while loop, it looks I have set up my "q" value in a way that im not able to go ahead. @Tas

Comment: You need to update both loops. As I mentioned in the answer, the reason you are getting seg faults is being you are creating a 0 sized array and then trying to access an element. Change your second loop, so that it writes the contents of your `vector<annotation_t> obj` instead. I'll update the answer.

Comment: that would be helpful im getting lost on adapting my for loop to your std::vector suggestion.

Comment: The code looks very good, one more thing, what I have to do to make sure the user will be able to input words using spaces? Because for example if I write more than one word on obj.topic string I'm not able to input at obj.comment, it goes straight to obj.stamp. The issues is that I have to keep "string" and not change to "char[]"

Comment: You should rightly keep `std::string` over `char[]`. `std::cin` only catches characters up to a space, so you should use [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) instead: `getline(std::cin, temp.topic);`

Comment: Perfect.and what about "q"?

Comment: `q` is an `int`, and therefore cannot have spaces, so it's fine to continue using `std::cin`